# Can someone explain to me how does this recursion program work?

Tags: python, recursion

[image]

I understand that the cursor first make a 90 degree turn to the left, then goes backward 100, and that where the recursion begins.

However, base on the order of the code in the tree function, the cursor will go forward 75, turn right 20 degree, then the recursion occur again and forward 75-15. This will happen 5 times with the last one only forward 10. Then the cursor will make the backward 10, then turn to the left for 40 degree, and so on.

This is where I got confused.

```
    def tree(branchLen,t)
    if (branchLen>5): 
    t.forward(branchLen)
    t.right(20)
    tree(branchLen-15,t)
    t.left(40)
    tree(branchLen-15,t)
    t.right(20)
    t.backward(branchLen)

def main():
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    myWin = turtle.Screen()
    t.left(90)
    t.up()
    t.backward(100)
    t.down()
    t.color("green")
    tree(75,t)
    myWin.exitonclick()
```

the program seems to jump into the last line of code then the middle one, then move forward 10, and so on, i just could not figure out how to follow the codes for the action they make. I undestand the graoh with one recursion, but this one really gives me headache.

Comment: Please, **put all relevant code in your question**. I it hard to read the code in your picture(for me at least).

Comment: i just added the rest. thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to get a successful recursive drawing with the Turtle is to leave the little turtle just at the same place where you found it. That way, you can call several functions one after the other and they will fit seamlessly.

In your specific code:

t.forward(branchLen)

It draws the branch.

```
t.right(20)
```

It rotates to the right to prepare for the first sub-branch.

```
tree(branchLen-15,t)
```

Draws a smaller sub-branch. Remember that upon returning from this sub-branch the turtle will be at the same place.

```
t.left(40)
```

It rolls back the previous turn (20) and rotates to the left (+20) to prepare for the second sub-branch.

```
tree(branchLen-15,t)
```

Draws the second sub-branch.

```
t.right(20)
t.backward(branchLen)
```

And these two lines are the key. The first one undoes the rotation so that the turtle is looking forward. The second line moves back to the starting point.

Comment: when the turtle starts to go backward, does it follow this order of the code? after move backward for 15, does it first turn right 20 degree, turn left 40 degree, and then turn right 20 degree, wait, isnn't it back to where it was pointing at? then how does it draw the first branch by moving forward 15?

Comment: @MichaelZeng: The order of the code? The code is always run in order, top to bottom. When you call a function, the turtle remembers the position in code and when the function ends, it continues from that position.

Comment: i am still confused. when the turtle reaches the end by moving forward 15, then it turns to the right for 20 degree, and because 15-15 is <5, so the tree(branchLen-15,t) will not be executed. Then, the turtle turns to the left for 40 degree, and again, the following the tree(branchLen-15,t) will not be executed will not be executed. the turtle then turn to the right for 20 degree, when it reaches the bottom line the turtle move backward 15. if the code is ran in order from top to bottom, the turtle then move forward 15 and repeat. isn't it the turtle will keep moving back and forth?

Comment: @MichaelZeng "...and repeat." Here is the cofusion. There are no loops in this code so no repetition. After moving back the function just finishes and goes back to the calling function.